# set scroll position when Show Div in a popup

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set the scroll position top of a `div` popup. It works the first time but after the position changes, it does not reset to `top`. Any ideas?

JS:

```
function ShowPopupAddLocations() {
    ClearPopUpData();
    $("#dividEditLocation").scrollTop();
    $('#dividEditLocation').show();
    return false;
}
```

CSS:

```
 .popOuter {background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); width:100%; height:100%; position:fixed; z-index:99; display:none; left:0; top:0;}
.popup_main{ padding:20px; box-sizing:border-box; max-width:700px; width:100%;  position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); background:#fafbff;}
.popup_main .popup_content{ position:relative; padding:20px 5px 0 0; max-height:500px; overflow-y:auto;}
.popup_main .popup_content p em{ font-size:20px;  color:#cc4b46; font-weight:700; font-style:normal}
.popup_header{ padding-bottom:15px; border-bottom:1px solid #e5e6ea;  }
.popup_header h2{ font-size:28px; line-height:30px;}
.popup_close{background:#fafbff url(../images/popclose_btn.png) no-repeat center center; width:20px; height:20px; top:10px; right:10px; position:absolute;}
```

**Edit**

this is div which is opened

```
<div class="popOuter" id="dividEditLocation"> <div class="popup_main">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="popup_close" onclick='funcHideAddressPopUp();'></a>
<div class="popup_header"> <h2>Create Location</h2> </div> 
<div class="popup_content" id="dvAddEditLocationDetail"> </div> </div> </div>
```

Comment: you actually have an element with an id of `dividEditLocation`? must be a bit unwieldy.

Comment: this is div which is opened <div class="popOuter" id="dividEditLocation">
        <div class="popup_main">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="popup_close" onclick='funcHideAddressPopUp();'></a>
            <div class="popup_header">
                <h2>Create Location</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="popup_content" id="dvAddEditLocationDetail">
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: can you provide absolute urls for these images?

Comment: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/co32mo2g/) is a fiddle, but I can't do anything without the images.

Comment: completely confused, can you describe your end goal a little further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you switch

```
$('#dividEditLocation').show();
$("#dividEditLocation").scrollTop();
```

It could work - the div doesn´t have any height so it donesn´t have scrollbar.